# c# datagridview cell event only triggers once

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a datagridview with some datagridviewimagecolumn.  The datagridview has  cellcontentclick event as it is an image column (is this correct). When I click on the image it takes me to another dialog so I can choose an image. So far all works.

Now when it returns the image is good and shown. I then do a dataGridView2.ClearSelection() to deselect all cells. Next if I click again into the same cell the event does not trigger but if I click in another cell and then back into this cell it will trigger. I looked for things like reset events etc but cannot see anything helpful. How do I fix this?

Here is some code does this help:

clicking on the cell enters into this section

```
else if (e.ColumnIndex.ToString() == "3")
            {
                try
                {

                    display_label = new ChooseLabel(dataGridView2[3, e.RowIndex].Tag.ToString()); // open dalog to choose the format
                    display_label.ShowDialog(this); // this to get the dialog to open on the same screen as the app

                    //when the Display_Layouts dialog closes we retrieve the data and use it here

                    BitmapFilenameToDisplay = display_label.txtbx_layout_bitmap.Text;

                    Image.GetThumbnailImageAbort myCallback = new Image.GetThumbnailImageAbort(ThumbnailCallback);
                    Label_Bitmap = new Bitmap(BitmapFilenameToDisplay);

                    dataGridView2[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value = Label_Bitmap.GetThumbnailImage(175, 100, myCallback, IntPtr.Zero); //create a bitmap of the image

                    // file_name = display_label.txtbx_layout_bitmap.Text; // bitmap to showtxtbx_layout_bitmap
                    dataGridView2[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Tag = display_label.txtbx_choice.Text + ".bmp"; //BitmapFilenameToDisplay; //  + ".bmp";

                    try
                    {
                        BitmapFilenameToDisplay = LayoutPath + dataGridView2[2, e.RowIndex].Tag.ToString();
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        BitmapFilenameToDisplay = LayoutPath + "blank.bmp";
                    }

                    fill_in_graphics_data(e.RowIndex);

                    Layout_Bitmap = new Bitmap(BitmapFilenameToDisplay);

                    dataGridView2[1, e.RowIndex].Value = MergeTwoImages(Layout_Bitmap, Label_Bitmap).GetThumbnailImage(175, 100, myCallback, IntPtr.Zero);

              dataGridView2.ClearSelection()

                }
                catch
                {
                    showmessagebox(strings.label_preview_problem, "100");
                    //MessageBox.Show("Please try again to choose a Label Preview");
                }
            }
```

As we enter this code we have

```
         display_label = new ChooseLabel(dataGridView2[3, e.RowIndex].Tag.ToString()); // open dalog to choose the format
```

and this opens a dialog that goes to a folder and shows me all the bitmaps in the folder and I choose the dialog and return here. Next you see the code for the dialog that opens.

```
public ChooseLabel(string choosen_bitmap)
        {
            //
            // The InitializeComponent() call is required for Windows Forms designer support.
            //
            InitializeComponent();

            MainForm defaultpaths = new MainForm();
            LayoutsPath = defaultpaths.txtbx_eggboxlabels_path.Text + "\\";

            // string folder_path1 = Application.StartupPath; // get the current path       //System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(); 

            string file_name = "";

            //  Format_bitmap_path = folder_path1 + "\\graphics\\" + nozzle + "\\" + format + "\\";

            int grid_y = 0, grid_x = 0, index = 0, array_length = 0, num_rows = 1, num_bmp = 1;

            DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(LayoutsPath); //Path to the images
            FileInfo[] Files = d.GetFiles("*.bmp"); //Getting image file names into an array
            array_length = Files.Length;

            int remainder = (array_length % num_col);

            if (remainder != 0)
            {
                num_rows = (array_length / num_col) + 1; // add extra row as we have more bitmaps but not a full row.
            }
            else
            {
                num_rows = (array_length / num_col);
            }

            //loop round all the cells and make the NULL image blank. 
            foreach (var column in dataGridView1.Columns)
            {
                if (column is DataGridViewImageColumn)
                    (column as DataGridViewImageColumn).DefaultCellStyle.NullValue = null;
            }


            while (grid_x < num_rows)
            {

                grid_x = grid_x + 1;
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
            }

            grid_x = 0;


            while ((grid_y < num_col) & (num_bmp <= array_length))
            {

                file_name = Files[index].ToString();

                Image.GetThumbnailImageAbort myCallback = new Image.GetThumbnailImageAbort(ThumbnailCallback);
                Bitmap myBitmap = new Bitmap(@LayoutsPath + file_name);

                dataGridView1[grid_y, grid_x].Value = myBitmap.GetThumbnailImage(350, 200, myCallback, IntPtr.Zero);  //create a bitmap of the image
                dataGridView1[grid_y, grid_x].Tag = file_name.Substring(0, file_name.LastIndexOf('.'));  //remove the extension and add to TAG
                dataGridView1[grid_y+1, grid_x].Value = file_name.Substring(0, file_name.LastIndexOf('.'));  //remove the extension and add to TAG
                dataGridView1[grid_y + 1, grid_x].Tag = file_name.Substring(0, file_name.LastIndexOf('.'));

                grid_y = grid_y + 1;

                index = index + 1;
                num_bmp = num_bmp + 1;

                if ((num_bmp <= array_length) & (grid_y >= num_col))
                {
                    grid_y = 0;
                    grid_x = grid_x + 1;
                }
            }

            dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false; // add this so we do not get the extra row at the bottom


            //fill in the data coming from the mainform.

            string cell_to_highlight = choosen_bitmap.Substring(0, choosen_bitmap.LastIndexOf('.'));

            txtbx_choice.Text = cell_to_highlight;
            txtbx_layout_bitmap.Text = LayoutsPath + cell_to_highlight + ".bmp";

            //work out which cell to highlight.
            for (int i = 0; i < (dataGridView1.Rows.Count); i++)
            {
                if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Tag.ToString() == cell_to_highlight)
                {
                    dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0];
                }
            }
        }
```

when I return to main grid cell I have focus on it but clicking the same cell does not seem to fire the event.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. You need to show more code, including the types of the neighbouring columns.  It works fine here, so there must be something else in your code. What does the part do _another dialog so I can choose an image._ ?

Comment: Set a breakpoint at the starting brace of your CellContentClick and see if the clicking fires the event. All in all you gotta provide the code for us to be able to help.

Comment: Note: CellContentclick only triggers if you actually hit the content. So if the new Iamge is smaller and you hit the empty area around it it will not triggeer. Usually CellClick is to be preferred